# What is the ratio between small and big x-gons?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, algebra

I have been checking [Gamow's question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29623/the-adventitious-18-gon) and noticed something! If we draw all diagonals there is a little polygon in the middle of the original polygon if it is odd-gon (odd-gon is defined as the number of vertices is an odd number.). For example;

[image]

So if you draw a regular pentagon on a piece of paper and draw all diagonals, there is a new pentagon in the middle of our original pentagon (shown as darker).

The area-ratio between the small and original pentagon is 6.854.

> **Question 1:** What is the area-ratio between the small and original 99-gons of 99-gon where 99 is number of vertices of the polygon?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there any formula that you can derive for the area-ratio between the small and original x-gons of x-gon where x is number of vertices of the polygon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inscribe the original $n$-gon in a circle of radius 1. The apothem of the large $n$-gon is $\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$ and the apothem of the small $n$-gon is $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})$. Therefore the ratio of their areas is $\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})}\right)^2$. For $n=99$ this is about $3968.53$.

Demonstration on a heptagon:

[image]

$OA=1$, $\angle OAB=\frac{\pi}{2n}$, $\angle AOC=\frac{\pi}{n}$ so $OB=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})$ and $OC=\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$.