# A geometric puzzle. What is the angle?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, triangle

This is a simply stated geometry puzzle. What is the angle p in this isosceles triangle?

[image: image of triangle1]

Here's some information about the origin of the puzzle. Following any links therein may spoil the fun if you were planning to solve the puzzle yourself.

> The puzzle was originally published in the *Mathematical Gazette*'s puzzle/problem section in 1922; it was problem number 644, published in volume 11. It is due to [Edward Mann Langley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Mann_Langley), a mathematics teacher and author, and has come to be known as [Langley's Adventitious Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles). It's related to multiple intersections of diagonals in a regular 18-gon; see e.g. [this puzzle here on Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29623/the-adventitious-18-gon); the "adventitious" in the name is because it seems somehow arbitrary and random that the relevant three diagonals should meet at a point, or that all the angles in the quadrangle BCDE (including the ones formed by the diagonals) should be rational numbers of degrees.

Comment: This is (I think -- I haven't checked it's exactly the same one as I'm thinking of) a famous -- and famously harder-than-it-looks-like-it-should-be -- puzzle. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find it's been asked here before, but if so finding the previous one might be difficult...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Could be.  Please don't spoil the answer if you find it!

Comment: Well, if it's a duplicate then we need to mark it as such. But I haven't found another instance on the site _yet_...

Comment: Is ABC isosceles?

Comment: That's certainly so in the original question. I suspect you can't solve the problem without that assumption. @Anush?

Comment: @loopywalt Updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway: I found another instance of the puzzle. It was deleted, along with many others, because (IIRC) the person who'd posted it was copying problems wholesale from external sources and refused to give those sources appropriate credit according to the rules we have here. So I think it's currently not a duplicate. But seeing that reminds me that we _do_ have those rules. Unfortunately, giving the actual origin of the puzzle also makes it trivial to find the solution with a quick web search. So [... continues]

Comment: ... let's say that once the problem is solved, or once a reasonable time has passed, it needs editing to credit the original creator of the problem. Anush, if you happen not to know who that is, I do :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thanks, I don't. The image itself is not copied if that matters .

Comment: Nope. This isn't about copyright concerns, but about giving proper credit for puzzle creation :-). (I mean, users should _also_ not post things that are copyright violations, but that isn't the main point of our rules about this sort of thing.)

Comment: The closest I found is [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/29623/20814) previous question, but even saying the title of that question is a spoiler for this one.

Comment: Could everyone please focus on solving my puzzle  rather than giving hints away :)

Comment: It seems assignment question than a puzzle to me. @Anush can you include source?

Comment: Now that a couple of answers have been posted, I have edited the question to say a bit about the source.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle  - it provides various nice solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a geometric proof:

> First, by tracing angles we can identify a couple of isosceles triangles, highlighted in colour:
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  M is the midpoint of AB
>  
>  Angles: <ABD = <BAC = 20°
>  
>  <ADX = <BDX = <DYX = 70°
>  
>  [ <BCE = <BEC = 50° ] Not needed as far as I can tell.

> Next, dropping perpendiculars from X to AD and DB construct the points P and Q. Observing that angle <ACX is 30°, we can see that 2 XP = 2 XQ = XC. Therefore, the configuration QXYCD is similar to MADCX. In particular, M is the midpoint of X and D, and triangle XED is isosceles.
>  
>  [image]

The angle p is therefore

> 70° - 40° = 30°

Answer (score 2):

Doing it the definitely *hard* way (and with some little cheating):

> Let's introduce a coordinate system with $BC=1$ and origin in $B$. So the equation of $BA$ straight is $y=\tan80^{\circ} x$ (since $\angle ABC=80^{\circ}$). Similarly, $CB$ is $y=-\tan80^{\circ} (x-1)$ (because $\angle ACB$ is also $80^{\circ}$. For the same reasons we get $CE$: $y=-\tan50^{\circ} (x-1)$ and $BD$: $y=\tan60^{\circ} x$. Now we can find the coordinates of $D$ and $E$:
>  $$D=\left(\frac{\tan80^{\circ}}{\tan60^{\circ}+\tan80^{\circ}}, \frac{\tan60^{\circ}\tan80^{\circ}}{\tan60^{\circ}+\tan80^{\circ}}\right)$$
>  $$E=\left(\frac{\tan50^{\circ}}{\tan50^{\circ}+\tan80^{\circ}}, \frac{\tan80^{\circ}\tan50^{\circ}}{\tan50^{\circ}+\tan80^{\circ}}\right)$$
>  To find $p$, we can use the formula for angle between the vectors $ED$ and $DB$ (parentheses indicate scalar product):
>  $$\cos p = \frac{(ED, DB)}{|ED|\times|DB|}=\frac{(x_E-x_D)x_D+(y_E-y_D)y_D}{\sqrt{(x_E-x_D)^2+(y_E-y_D)^2}\times\sqrt{x_D^2+y_D^2}}$$
>  Well, here must come the trig magic. Now, I've decided to cheat a bit and summon a sage... not, The [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/), plugging all the expressions and computing $p$ symbolically. Sage gave me that $p = 30^{\circ}$, which must be the answer.
>  Sage code (note that this gives 150 for $p$, probably due to sign error - it's clear that $p$ is an acute angle):
>
> ```
> t50 = tan(5 * pi / 18)
> t60 = tan(6 * pi / 18)
> t80 = tan(8 * pi / 18)
> xD = t80 / (t60 + t80)
> yD = t60 * t80 / (t60 + t80)
> xE = t50 / (t50 + t80)
> yE = t50 * t80 / (t50 + t80)
> c = (xD-xE)*xD + (yD-yE)*yD
> g = sqrt((xE-xD)^2+(yE-yD)^2)
> h = sqrt(xD^2+yD^2)
> p = acos(c / (g+h)) * 180 / pi
> ```

Comment: Can you include your sage code in the answer?

Comment: @Anush Thanks! I've included it.